# cant show image on pug

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="resources/mainlogo.png" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
<h1>Welcome to our user management application</h1>
<h3>Please see links below to navigate our homepage</h3>

<a href = /adduser>Create new user</a>
<a href = /users>List users</a>

</body>
</html>
```

everything **except** image is shown

Here is my file structure:

```
index.html
resources
  mainlogo.png
```

What am I doing wrong?

this is rendering code

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    // render main page
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");


});
```

Here is also error from console

```
Error http://localhost:8000/resources/mainlogo.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Despite image is inside resources folder.

Comment: i think i am sensing what can be issue. maybe I need to implement get for sending image separately?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the resources folder accessible via `express.static`. This should do the trick:

```
app.use(express.static('resources')); //This will allow express to access any file in that folder
```

Html:

```
...
<img src="mainlogo.png" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
...
```

Answer (score 0):

adding this

```
app.use(express.static('resources'))
```

and changing this

```
<img src="mainlogo.png" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
```

helped

Comment: Whoops! I added my answer right when you did. Probably would be better to have a folder called img under resources to organize your files better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the`express.static` middleware in order to serve static files like images and CSS files.

In you case, this should work:

```
app.use(express.static('resources'));
```

Checkout the static documentation for [displaying static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)